# How many years will be deducted, if education in MSc Physics and experience in software engineer

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, australia, australian-citizens

I have a Master Degree in Physics  and want to apply to the Australia Skilled visa, I don't know what exactly type of visa will be better for me but looks like Australia Skilled Independent visa: Permanent (subclass 189) will be good.

My main purpose is to live (with my wife). I happened to hear that if education is not matching to ICT there will be deduction in experience. I have 9 years of experience as software engineer. In my case, how many year will be deducted?

Comment: Loosely related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6318/do-i-need-a-degree-in-field-i-am-working-in-it-to-apply-for-australia-skilled

Answer (score 1):

6 years will be deducted under the RPL type application.

Edit: Source- Skills-Assessment-Guidelines-for-Applicants.pdf from the ACS website.

Comment: Adding a source or reference for this would be great, if you know of one!