# Can I apply for Australian PR (subclass 189) as IT professional if I have BSc in Civil Engg. and MSc in Transportation System?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, australia, pr

I have BSc in Civil engineering and Msc in Transportation System (ITS) and I have 3+ years of working experience as Software developer. I appeared in IELTS and made score 7 in all sections.

Will I be eligible to apply for PR (subclass 189) as IT professional in Australia provided I have different educational background ? It not, are there other paths I could take, for example, if I get another MSc in Computer science/ Information technology, will I be able to attain the requirement ? Please, advise.

Comment: Have you read the relevant [information published by the ACS](https://www.acs.org.au/migration-skills-assessment)? They are the only ones who can answer this definitively, and it will cost you money to find out. I'd recommend discussing your situation with a registered migration agent first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will find someone who practices within the region I located.

Comment: Good luck...! If you do use a migration agent, make sure that they are [registered](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Usin).

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6318/do-i-need-a-degree-in-field-i-am-working-in-it-to-apply-for-australia-skilled

Answer (score 1):

You could do. Vendor certifications are accepted as IT qualifications by the ACS ([page 10 of guidelines](https://www.acs.org.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/7319/Skills-Assessment-Guidelines-for-Applicants.pdf)). It would be quicker to get a Microsoft/Cisco etc.. qualification than a Masters. Note though it is a full certification you need not just passing one of the exams - well that is the case with the MS exams which I'm most familiar with. You can even get a positive assessment result with no IT qualifications at all by completing a Recognition of Prior Learning ([again see guidelines](https://www.acs.org.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/7319/Skills-Assessment-Guidelines-for-Applicants.pdf)).

Bear in mind though the lower your qualification the more years of experience you will need to offset this. Someone without an IT qualification would need 6 years more experience than someone with a BSc or Masters in IT in order to score the same points.

Good luck with your application